# Is it possible to get bbciplayer working on an arm v6 device?

Tags: media-player, adobe-air, armv6

Have been playing about flashing modded firmware to an older android device which has an arm v6 processor and have been disappointed in not being able to view any media through bbciplayer either through the app or online.

Checking out the bbc help pages regarding this is confusing as they confirm bbciplayer should run on android 2.1 and up.  The fairly recent addition of needing the bbcmediaplayer installed to play any bbc media through either the bbciplayer app or their website means that this device appears to be unable to play bbciplayer media at all.  After researching on bbc's help pages this is due to bbciplayer using adobe air 3 for which demands arm v7 minimum specification.

Is it possible to run adobe air 3 on an arm v6 device?

Answer (score 1):

Highly doubt it can be done, since Adobe Air v3 targets ARMv7 instruction set, its like comparing chalk and cheese in regards to both ARMv7 and ARMv6 instruction set.

So the chances of back-porting to the older instruction set is difficult to say the least, not alone that, it is a proprietary software so no going in there.

The trend is there and is to stay this way with the advent of increased hardware, supply/demand which dictates support ARMv7 and let ARMv6 die off.